# jupyter notebook security - limit maximum number of enter the token(password)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

friends. I do research using deep learning, and I do almost everything on Jupiter.

Recently, however, attempts to log in to my jupyter notebook from China began to be recorded. They failed to log in because they don't know the password, but my server is slowing down because I keep trying to connect.

I want to make it block access if someone incorrectly enter the password more than 3 times in jupyter notebook.

Does Jupiter support this feature?

Comment: You could use fail2ban. But a better question is why on earth is your Jupiter notebook publicly accessible via the internet?

Comment: @SumnerEvans. I have to connect to my server through public Wi-Fi. Thank you for your answer.